# using windows batch file I Executed a postgres select query, I need only the data(value alone) as output?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

For my select query:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tablename'))
```

It returns result like following.

```
pg_size_pretty
 -----------
    24 kB
   (1 row)
```

I need only 24 kB as output.

Comment: I don't really understand what's the question here. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--tuples-only` flag to `psql`:

```
psql databasename --tuples-only -c "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tablename'));"
```